# windows and ubuntu on ssd, another ubuntu on hdd, cannot access second ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

please help me.

On my pc i had a windows and an ubuntu (64-bit), installed on SSD. I needed a new (32-bit) ubuntu and i installed it on the HDD (a new 100GB partition, ext4 type).

Now, when i start pc, it goes in the normal boot menu where i have the old windows and the ubuntu. I went on the boot setting and i tried to boot from all the options i found, with the hope to find the new ubuntu instaled, but i didn't find it.

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to access the new ubuntu and add it in the boot menu near the old OSs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By normal boot menu, do you mean Grub? If so, try booting to Ubuntu and then open a Terminal window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Then try updating Grub to see if it recognizes the new installation with this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that doesn't work, you could try reinstalling Grub with:

```
sudo install-grub /dev/sda
```

Change `/dev/sda` to whatever your boot volume is.

Before doing either, it might be an idea to make sure you have a rescue disk on hand just in case something goes wrong and you can't access your OS anymore.

Comment: thank you very much, i have updated the grub and it work, i thought the problem appeared because of the two disks, but ir works now

Comment: Great - glad it worked. If the issue is now resolved, please mark the answer as accepted: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers